# I have 2 attacks. Can I shoot a light/heavy crossbow, then throw a dart in same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, actions, ranged-attack

I've tried to check Q&A before asking, but I haven't seen this question asked specifically.

If the loading property restricts me to firing my crossbow once per turn, may I throw an improvised or ranged martial weapon as a second attack? I do not have the Crossbow Expert feat.

I'm finding with *hunter's mark* and Colossus Slayer, an archery ranger would be more effective on average with throwing 2x darts than with firing one crossbow bolt.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49827/throwing-more-than-once-per-turn

Comment: A Longbow is a lot better than darts. [Crossbows without the relevant feat are subpar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134003/9552)

Answer (score 8):

## If the Crossbow was already loaded

Both heavy and light crossbows have the two-handed property, so you have to get the dart with your free object interaction.

### Bows are much better with Extra Attack

If you do *not* have the Crossbow Expert feat, even a Shortbow does better damage than any crossbow, or a Longbow better than Heavy crossbow + Dart.
If you *do* have Crossbow Expert, a Hand Crossbow provides best DPR.

There is no situation, where a non-hand crossbow is a good option for DPR if you have Extra Attack. I would argue even if you don't have EA, [Hand Crossbows are the only good crossbows](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134003/9552).

Comment: Since crossbows have the "ammunition" property, doesn't drawing a piece of ammunition and loading it into the weapon come for free as part of the attack with it (and not require a use of "interact with an object")? So couldn't you have an unloaded crossbow in a hand, then drawn and throw a dart, and then load and fire the crossbow? (Or vice-versa).

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme, you are right, it is such a stupid rule I did not consider it. "_Loading_" takes so much time you cannot do it twice, but so little it is not even using up your free object interaction.